# Setting IFrame size from within the IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying a few things like the following trying to get the iframe to be reset from within the iframe but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Ideas?

```
    window.top.$("#ID").width(324);
    window.top.$("#ID").height(369);
```

Has not worked.

Comment: It will only work if the top frame is from the same domain, has jQuery , and `ID` is the id of the iframe in it.